# Using checkbox and textbox for tip calculator

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, textbox

I am working on a project to make a tip calculator that has two check boxes 15% and 20% and a textbox that allows you to put in your own % in, I just can't figure out how to link the checkbox's and textbox to where they would affect the answer. I'm just hoping someone can point out whats needed to link these things together.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class TipCalc {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel lblTipAmount;
    private JTextField txtEnterBill;
    private JTextField txtCustomTip;
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TipCalc window = new TipCalc();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TipCalc() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        double percent = 1;
        double base = 1 * percent;

        JButton btnGetTip = new JButton("Get Tip");
        btnGetTip.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                double num1;
                double answer;
                Enumeration<AbstractButton> bg = buttonGroup.getElements();
                    while (bg.hasMoreElements()) {
                        JCheckBox jcb = (JCheckBox) bg.nextElement();
                            if(jcb.isSelected());
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello");
                    }



                try {
                    num1=Double.parseDouble(txtEnterBill.getText());

                                        answer=num1 * base;
                    lblTipAmount.setText(Double.toString(answer));
                } catch(Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter A valid Amount");
                }
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test");
                //lblTipAmount.setText("The Tip is:" + answer);

            }
        });
        btnGetTip.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        btnGetTip.setBounds(130, 121, 150, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetTip);

        txtEnterBill = new JTextField();
        txtEnterBill.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtEnterBill.setText("Enter Bill");
        txtEnterBill.setBounds(130, 11, 150, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtEnterBill);
        txtEnterBill.setColumns(10);

        lblTipAmount = new JLabel("Tip Amount");
        lblTipAmount.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTipAmount.setBounds(130, 201, 150, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTipAmount);

        JCheckBox checkBox15 = new JCheckBox("15%");
        buttonGroup.add(checkBox15);
        checkBox15.setBounds(130, 38, 97, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBox15);

        if (checkBox15.isSelected())
            percent = (double) 1.15;

        JCheckBox checkBox20 = new JCheckBox("20%");
        buttonGroup.add(checkBox20);
        checkBox20.setBounds(130, 64, 97, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(checkBox20);

        txtCustomTip = new JTextField();
        txtCustomTip.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            }
        });
        txtCustomTip.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        txtCustomTip.setText("Custom Tip In % or Decimal\r\n");
        txtCustomTip.setBounds(125, 94, 160, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtCustomTip);
        txtCustomTip.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to pop a JOptionPane from inside your ActionListener - you are blocking the event thread.  You should check for valid entries when the user types a value in, not when the user clicks on the getTip button.

Comment: @FredK While I'm not a big fan of post validation, there is no issue with doing so in this case, as the `JOptionPane`, via the `JDialog` API will take over control of the event dispatching, preventing the UI from been blocked, but preventing the user from been able to interact with the parent window, this is how dialogs work and is perfectly safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is, check each `JCheckBox` to see if it's selected and based on which one is selected, assign the amount it represents to some variable.  This would require you to know something about the `JCheckBox` in question.

You could:

- use instance fields and simply check each instance field to see if they are selected, this becomes an issue if you have a large number of fields
- use the components `putClientProperty` to `getClientProperty` capabilities to store an object against a key within each field, personally, this is a little dirty and because you need to do object casting, error prone
- use some kind of model and the `Action` API

This example makes use of a simple "model" and the `Action` API to setup the basic functionality.

The "model" maintains the currently selected percentage.  When one of the available options is selected, the model is updated automatically.  When the user presses the "calculate" button, the tip percentage is obtained from the "model" and the calculate is made

[image: Tip calculator]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JSpinner subTotal;
        private JSpinner custom;
        private JButton btnCalculate;

        private TipModel model;

        private JLabel tipAmountLabel;
        private JLabel billTotalLabel;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            subTotal = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel());
            subTotal.setValue(0d);
            subTotal.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(subTotal, "$#0.0#"));

            model = new TipModel();

            custom = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1, 0.05));
            custom.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(custom, "##%"));

            JCheckBox cb15 = new JCheckBox(new TipAction(model, 0.15d));
            JCheckBox cb20 = new JCheckBox(new TipAction(model, 0.20d));
            JCheckBox cbCustom = new JCheckBox(new CustomTipAction(model, custom));

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(cb15);
            bg.add(cb20);
            bg.add(cbCustom);

            btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate Tip");
            btnCalculate.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

            tipAmountLabel = new JLabel("...");
            billTotalLabel = new JLabel("...");
            billTotalLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            tipAmountLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            add(subTotal, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            add(cb15, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(cb20, gbc);
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(cbCustom, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(custom, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(btnCalculate, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(tipAmountLabel, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(billTotalLabel, gbc);

            btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    double tipPercentage = model.getTipPercentage();

                    if (tipPercentage > 0.0) {

                        double subTotalAmount = (double) subTotal.getValue();
                        double tipAmount = subTotalAmount * tipPercentage;
                        double billTotal = subTotalAmount + tipAmount;

                        tipAmountLabel.setText("Tip amount: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tipAmount));
                        billTotalLabel.setText("Bill total: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(billTotal));

                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestPane.this, "Please provide a valid tip percentage");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public class TipModel {

            private double tipPercentage;

            public double getTipPercentage() {
                return tipPercentage;
            }

            public void setTipPercentage(double tipPercentage) {
                this.tipPercentage = tipPercentage;
            }

        }

        public class TipAction extends AbstractAction {

            private TipModel model;
            private double tipPercentage;

            public TipAction(TipModel model, double tipPercentage) {
                this.model = model;
                this.tipPercentage = tipPercentage;
                putValue(NAME, NumberFormat.getPercentInstance().format(tipPercentage));
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setTipPercentage(tipPercentage);
            }

        }

        public class CustomTipAction extends AbstractAction {

            private TipModel model;
            private JSpinner spinner;

            public CustomTipAction(TipModel model, JSpinner spinner) {
                this.model = model;
                this.spinner = spinner;

                spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        model.setTipPercentage((double) spinner.getValue());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setTipPercentage((double) spinner.getValue());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Have a look at:

- [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)
- [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

for more details